# Instantiate beans in order in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Is it possible to set order of instantiation in Spring?

I don't want to use `@DependsOn` and I don't want to use `Ordered` interface. I just need an order of instantiation.

The following usage of `@Order` annotation does not work:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

/**
 * Order does not work here
 */
public class OrderingOfInstantiation {

   public static class MyBean1 {{
      System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
   }}

   public static class MyBean2 {{
      System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
   }}

   @Configuration
   public static class Config {

      @Bean
      @Order(2)
      public MyBean1 bean1() {
         return new MyBean1();
      }

      @Bean
      @Order(1)
      public MyBean2 bean2() {
         return new MyBean2();
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
   }

}
```

Beans are still instantiated in lexicographic order.

Why it does not work here?

Can I rely of lexicographic order anyway?

**UPDATE**

I would like any solution allowing to provide order of creation.

The goal is to populate collections at config level in correct order. `Depends on` -- does not match the task. Any "explanations" on why Spring does not like to have ordered instantiations -- also does not match the task.

Order means order :)

Comment: Spring detects the order it self depending on the dependencies of the beans and the `@DependsOn`. The `@Ordered` or `Ordered` interface serves an entirely different purpose so that attempt will be futile. The only thing that will work is `@DependsOn`. But why is the order important how beans are created? The only thing that *might* work is to define each bean in its own `@Configuration` and order those (but that would only work on recent versions of Spring or Spring Boot).

Comment: The reason is that I am wishing to populate collections at config level. There is no difference between instantiation of a bean with correctly filled properties. Collections should also be in correct order. Orderless population mean the same thing as if one were unable to inject beans under correct name.

Comment: You are trying to do something spring isn't intended to do. If you want to populate a collection then populate a collection in the order you wish. Create the beans, create the collection still the order of the beans doesn't matter. Next to that spring can automatically populate a collection with all i stances of a certain bean, in a certain order if those beans are ordered (still the order in which they are instantiated don't matter, they will be ordered in the end). I suggest you put a sample up on what you really want to achieve as the sample you added isn't what you actually want to do.

Comment: I want to define order inside element instantiation code. This is very popular technique, for example, coordinates of children in 3D engines are kept inside children, not inside parent. In GUI constraints of the children also kept inside children. The order can be regarded as a property of a child, not a parent, so it should be set at children instantiation. I don't see any reason Spring "isn't intended to do" so. If it isn't then it should.

Comment: That comment doesn't make any sense and still if it is property of the bean instance then make it a property of the bean instance and order a collection on that property. Don't make it part of the recipe (the bean definition) but of the actual bean.

Comment: Spring should do dependency injection, it is it's job, not mine. In your words, it IS intended to do so. Limiting dependencies by mapped ones only is not justified.

Comment: Correct and it will do injection but what you want is that it also somehow magically orders that when it isn't really needed. What you also describe is that it should be part of your object and not part of the recipe. Heck it will even do what you want if you simply inject everything in a collection then it will honour the ordering, but that ordering shouldn't influence the instantiation order. That is my main point.

Comment: Spring allows to inject by class, Spring allows to inject by name. Why doesn't it allow to inject by order?.. I agree that I was incorrect requesting order of instantiation, I would better say order of injection. Is it what supported?

Comment: In a collection it will honour the ordering you specified, but that will only work for beans of the same (parent) type i.e (`List<YourInterface>` it will inject all beans of type `YourInterface` and honour the ordering).. For single fields  it will not honor the order because there is little reason to do so.

Comment: What if my collection is [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), i.e. doesn't implement `List<MyInterface>`. Or may be I have some third-party collection like [`ListModel<MyInterface>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) how it change the situation in principle?

Comment: Then make it `List<JPanel>` it should still be ordered that is if it is `@Autowired` or filled by doing a lookup of all `JPanel` beans at once. What I was referring to was the type of the collection in the parent you want to inject the child into. i.e. `@Autowired List<JPanel> panels;`.

Comment: Sorry, we probably have a misunderstanding here. I meant that `JPanel` IS a collection of components (actually, since it contains children of type `Component`), but it doesn't implement `List<Component>`. How to populate it in order?

Comment: Please put that in your question and how you are adding the components to the `JPanel`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `@Order` javadoc

> NOTE: Annotation-based ordering is supported **for specific kinds of components only** — for example, for annotation-based AspectJ aspects. Ordering strategies within the Spring container, on the other hand, are typically based on the Ordered interface in order to allow for programmatically configurable ordering of each instance.

So I guess Spring just doesn't follow `@Order()` when creating beans.

But if you just want to populate collections, maybe this is good enough for you:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.google.common.collect.MultimapBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class OrderingOfInstantiation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(OrderingOfInstantiation.class);
    }

    @Component
    @CollectionOrder(collection = "myBeans", order = 1)
    public static class MyBean1 {{
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
    }}

    @Component
    @CollectionOrder(collection = "myBeans", order = 2)
    public static class MyBean2 {{
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
    }}

    @Configuration
    public static class CollectionsConfig {

        @Bean
        List<Object> myBeans() {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    // PopulateConfig will populate all collections beans
    @Configuration
    public static class PopulateConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            Multimap<String, Object> beansMap = MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().arrayListValues().build();

            // get all beans
            applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(CollectionOrder.class)
                    .values().stream()

                    // get CollectionOrder annotation
                    .map(bean -> Pair.of(bean, bean.getClass().getAnnotation(CollectionOrder.class)))

                    // sort by order
                    .sorted((p1, p2) -> p1.getRight().order() - p2.getRight().order())

                    // add to multimap
                    .forEach(pair -> beansMap.put(pair.getRight().collection(), pair.getLeft()));

            // and add beans to collections
            beansMap.asMap().entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
                Collection collection = applicationContext.getBean(entry.getKey(), Collection.class);
                collection.addAll(entry.getValue());

                // debug
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":");
                collection.stream()
                        .map(bean -> bean.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
            });
        }

    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
    @Documented
    public @interface CollectionOrder {
        int order() default 0;

        String collection();
    }
}
```

It won't change instantiation order, but you'll get ordered collections.

Comment: Sorry for everybody, but I think this answer is the most close to what I thought.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to make sure that a specific bean is created before another bean you can use the @DependsOn annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

   @Bean 
   public Foo foo() {
   ...
   }

   @Bean
   @DependsOn("foo")
   public Bar bar() {
   ...
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that this does not set the order, it only guarantees that the bean "foo" is created before "bar".
[JavaDoc for @DependsOn](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

Comment: I would like an order.

Comment: Does it work for all scoped bean ? , i just try working with request bean , it doesn't work as expected in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can impose ordering in your example by first eliminating static on the classes `MyBean1` and `MyBean2`, which when using Spring is not necessary in almost every case, as the default for Spring is to instantiate a single instance of each bean (similar to a Singleton).

The trick is to declare `MyBean1` and `MyBean2` as `@Bean` and to enforce the order, you create an implicit dependency from bean1 to bean2 by calling bean2's bean initialization method from within bean1's initialization method.

For example:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

/**
 * Order does not work here
 */
public class OrderingOfInstantiation {

   interface MyBean{
       default String printSimpleName(){
           System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
       }
   }

   public class MyBean1 implments MyBean{ 
       public MyBean1(){ pintSimpleName(); }
   }

   public class MyBean2 implments MyBean{ 
       public MyBean2(){ pintSimpleName(); }
   }

   public class MyBean3 implments MyBean{ 
       public MyBean3(){ pintSimpleName(); }
   }

   public class MyBean4 implments MyBean{ 
       public MyBean4(){ pintSimpleName(); }
   }

   public class MyBean5 implments MyBean{ 
       public MyBean5(){ pintSimpleName(); }
   }

   @Configuration
   public class Config {

      @Bean
      MyBean1 bean1() {
         //This will cause a a dependency on bean2
         //forcing it to be created before bean1
         bean2();

         return addToAllBeans(new MyBean1());
      }

      @Bean
      MyBean2 bean2() {
         //This will cause a a dependency on bean3
         //forcing it to be created before bean2
         bean3();

         //Note: This is added just to explain another point
         //Calling the bean3() method a second time will not create
         //Another instance of MyBean3. Spring only creates 1 by default
         //And will instead look up the existing bean2 and return that.
         bean3();

         return addToAllBeans(new MyBean2());
      }

      @Bean
      MyBean3 bean3(){ return addToAllBeans(new MyBean3()); }

      @Bean
      MyBean4 bean4(){ return addToAllBeans(new MyBean4()); }


      @Bean
      MyBean5 bean5(){ return addToAllBeans(new MyBean5()); }


      /** If you want each bean to add itself to the allBeans list **/
      @Bean
      List<MyBean> allBeans(){
          return new ArrayList<MyBean>();
      }

      private <T extends MyBean> T addToAllBeans(T aBean){
          allBeans().add(aBean);
          return aBean;
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer to show now to return a List of beans, preserving desired order.

Comment: The idea was each bean definition should also add itself to the list, and list should be instantiated empty

Comment: The answer has been updated to show how to populate a Collection in a desired order. And actually, this is not a dependOn. DependsOn means to always instantiate another bean before this bean, even if the other bean is not being used. In this case, you are 'using' the other bean, so of course it must be instantiated and available before this bean. This is load order based on usage, not a forced dependency, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the method described above has no use cases beyond academic 'Yes! I can do it!', without thinking of consequences in actual applications.
The consequences I can think of immediately:
 - Reordering is a nightmare. Imagine adding bean with order 5 into an existing chain of 10 beans,
 - Constructor arguments hell. Beans have their instantiation arguments, chaining beans creation requires adding all the arguments to individual bean creation methods, and decreasing them as you use them up. A total mess.