# Using @Bean and @PostConstruct in Spring config

Tags: java, spring

I need to define a class GameUpdateQueueListener as a Spring bean like this, inside a Spring config class:

```
    @Bean
    GameUpdateQueueListener gameUpdateQueueListener() {
        GameUpdateQueueListener listener = new GameUpdateQueueListener();
        List<EventProcessor> eventProcessors = new ArrayList<>();
        eventProcessors.add(new ContestStartProcessor());
        eventProcessors.add(new ScoreUpdateProcessor());
        eventProcessors.add(new ContestEndProcessor());
        listener.getEventProcessors().addAll(eventProcessors);
        return listener;
    }
```

I need to autowire GameUpdateQueueListener and call a member method of the GameUpdateQueueListener within a @PostConstruct

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void startGameUpdateQueueListener() {
        listener.queryAndUpdateGame();
    }
```

Shall I define both in the same config or do I need to include them in separate config files?

Comment: When you say "autowire", do you mean that the listener itself has bean dependencies? If so, the preferred approach is to use constructor parameters instead of field magic, and you can often get rid of `@PostConstruct` methods entirely in this case.

Comment: The listener has a set of autowired dependencies with an instance variable of a type List<EventProcessor>. I need to config the listener as a Bean and run the method when the application starts.

Comment: also you can use `@DependsOn` and call `gameUpdateQueueListener()` in another bean. see this post for using it. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36187588/5456789)

Comment: Just add the `queryAndUpdateGame` as the `init-method` on the `@Bean` annotation. Or even better just annotate that method with `@PostConstruct` (if you can). Don't try to be smarter then the framework(s) you use.