# In Spring Boot which class would be initialize first @Component or @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class annotated with `@Component` which is use to initialze application.yml config properties. Service classe is using configuration property. But sometime my Service class instance created before the Configuration class and I get null property value in service class, Its random not specific pattern.

Configuration Initializer class..

```
@Component
public class ConfigInitializer implements InitializingBean {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigInitializer.class);
    @Autowired
    ProxyConfig proxyConfig;

    /*@PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        setProperties();
    }
    */
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        setProperties();
    }
    private void setSystemProperties(){
        log.debug("Setting properties...");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("PROXY_URL", proxyConfig.getProxyUrl());
        props.put("PROXY_PORT", proxyConfig.getProxyPort());
        System.getProperties().putAll(props);
    }
} 


@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "proxy-config")
public static class ProxyConfig {
    private String proxyUrl;
    private String proxyPort;

    public String getProxyUrl() {
        return proxyUrl;
    }

    public void setProxyUrl(String proxyUrl) {
        this.proxyUrl = proxyUrl;
    }

    public String getProxyPort() {
        return proxyPort;
    }

    public void setProxyPort(String proxyPort) {
        this.proxyPort = proxyPort;
    }

}
```

Service Class..

```
@Service("receiverService")
public class ReceiverService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReceiverService.class);
    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @Autowired
    public ReceiverService() {
        initClient();
    }

    private void initClient() {
        Future future = executorService.submit(new Callable(){
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                String value = System.getProperty("PROXY_URL"); **//Here I am getting null**    
                logger.info("Values : " + value); 
            }
        });

        System.out.println("future.get() = " + future.get());
    }
}
```

Above Service class get `null` values `String value = System.getProperty("PROXY_URL")` 
When I use `@DependsOn` annotation on Service class, it works fine.
In my little knowledge, I know Spring does not have specific order of bean creation.

I want to know If I use `@Configuration` instead of `@Component` on `ConfigInitializer` class like below, Will spring initialize ConfigInitializer 
 class before other beans ?.

```
  @Configuration    
  public class ConfigInitializer implements InitializingBean { 
    //code here
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187063/instantiate-beans-in-order-in-spring can helps.

Comment: There's an easier way to do: Wired the proxy config instead. Why do you have to read it from System.getProperties?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn In real there is not only proxy configuration other properties are also in application.yml, I am storing values in System properties at the time when bean is created first so that I can use values at any place in application.

Comment: All configuration properties are available for you. Do not use the hard way.